# c# Constructor Action from Interface (NServiceBus)

Tags: c#, reflection, action, nservicebus

I have this code, which works well,

```
void Message(IMessage m)
{
    m.MyProperty = "Some Value";
}
await context.Publish<IMessage>(Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have a contract (IMessage) and create a constructor for an action that is to be published.

But I want to be able to create the action from a string. I.e. from this starting point,

```
var messageType = "IMessage";
```

I want to be able to send the same message as above.

This may not be the best way to do what I want to do, but it would be really interesting if it can be done.

Comment: Have you looked at Activator.CreateInstanceFrom() ? Althouigh I don't think that will work with Interfaces

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for interfaces :(

Comment: _endpointInstance.Send<_messageType>(messageConstructor: message =>
{
    message.Prop = "some text";
});

Answer (score 1):

Seems like NServiceBus RAW might be a good fit for this. Not sure what you are up to but that allows you do define your own payload:

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rawmessaging/

Comment: The messaging is working correctly. It's more a question about creating the messages dynamically from the contract interface.